# Sprintf() error

Tags: c++, printf

There is a `Binary2String()` in my project.

It works well for a long time. But it threw exception when `vec[0] = 255` on `sprintf(temp, "%02d ", vec[i]);`.

Original Code as this,

```
void Binary2String(const vector<unsigned char>& vec, string& result)
{

 if(vec.size() == 0)
  return;

 for(size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
 {
  char temp[4] = {0};
  sprintf(temp, "%02d ", vec[i]);
  result.push_back(temp[0]);
  result.push_back(temp[1]);
  result.push_back(temp[2]);

 }
}
```

Then I fixed the bug as this, I can't understand the vector and sprintf() completed.

Does it make sense or not? (I am new to C++. Thank you)

```
        char temp[6] = {0};
  sprintf(temp, "%02d ", vec[i]);
  result.push_back(temp[0]);
  result.push_back(temp[1]);
  result.push_back(temp[2]);
        result.push_back(temp[3]);
  result.push_back(temp[4]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `%02d` is not the correct format since values can go up to 3 digits (`%03d` would be more appropriate). And as Chris states in the comment below, `%03hhu` would be the technically correct specifier (to understand `%03hhu`, take a look at [this cheat sheet](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/gcc/format_specs.html)).

Second, You need 5 bytes to store the chars "2", "5", "5", " ", 0 (you have an extra space at the end of `%02d`). Either drop the space, or extend the buffer to at least 5 chars (as you have done).

Finally, you can convert to string much more reliably this way:

```
template<typename T> std::string ToString(const T& in) {
    std::basic_ostringstream<char> o;
    if (!(o << in)) {
        // error, throw an exception
    }
    return o.str();
}
```

Comment: `%03hhu` would be _most_ appropriate, since it isn't a signed type and it's not `int` sized.

Comment: Thank you for the cheat sheet. I've wanted something like that for ages. Didn't knew someone had taken the time to write it.